# swift play list play selected song

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, avplayer

I can't find a way online who explains how to play a song when you select an item in the tableview. I have all the external urls loaded in an array called track_url.

I know i need to do something in the tableview function didselectrowatindexpath. BUt i can't figure out how to set the url for the avplayer when i click on a cell.

Can some one share the code with me so i can get the url to load in the avplayer. I can only find stuff rhat is about pars and uses pfobect. I just have it all appended to a var. This came from json done with swiftyjason.

I hope some one can give me a suction/example so i can understand this. I am very new to swift.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple's QA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html), you *cannot* stream audio with `AVAudioPlayer`:

> The `AVAudioPlayer` class does not provide support for streaming audio based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with `initWithContentsOfURL:` must be a File URL (file://). That is, a local path.

Fortunately, the same QA says that you *can* stream with `AVPlayer`:

```
import AVFoundation
var player: AVPlayer?

func playSong(url: NSURL) {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url)
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player?.play()
}
```

To try it out with iOS 9, you should also (temporarily) add a `NSAppTransportSecurity` dictionary with a `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` Boolean key to your `Info.plist`.